John 5: Pool of Bethesda: Real or or folklore?
Was the Pool of Bethesda real (I mean, did actual angels come to heal people there), or was it just a legend meant to attract attention? I know there is a related question here: What might have 'stirred up' Jerusalem’s pool of Bethzatha in John 5:1-7 My question focuses on whether the Pool of Bethesda is real or simply folklore. Is there any historical evidence or documentation outside the Bible?

John refers to 'sheep' not 'sheep gate'. John refers to a 'messenger' who troubles the waters. I strongly suspect that John himsef does not believe the scam that was going on. 'Bethesda' has no authenticity in the Hebrew scripture. And the cruelty involved in having disabled people compete, hobbling, dragging themselves, limping . . . .  to be first : is this Divine ? Or even angelic ? Personally, I think they were making money out of the refreshments as all waited for the next 'messenger' to quietly 'trouble' the water. But I cannot prove it. So a comment, not an answer.

It sounds like you are interested in only the validity of the healing - not the actual existence of the pool. What would you consider proof that the healing properties of the pool were real? Would testimony of healed individuals suffice? Would stories that people dedicated time and effort seeking the healing count as proof?

@David D It's actually a question of textual criticism. KJV and others includes the angel in vs 5:4. NIV, RSV, NABRE and others do not, because this verse is not found in older manuscripts.

The physical pool was real, and there is no reason to doubt that the water indeed moved. But as far as the text is concerned, the answer to the OP depends on the manuscript. The earliest versions do not mention an angel. However later versions, which are often used in English translation, do speak of an angel stirring the water to produce healing. According to a footnote in the NABRE, which does not include the verse about the angel:

Toward the end of the second century in the West and among the
fourth-century Greek Fathers, an additional verse was known: “For
[from time to time] an angel of the Lord used to come down into the
pool; and the water was stirred up, so the first one to get in [after
the stirring of the water] was healed of whatever disease afflicted
him.” The angel was a popular explanation of the turbulence and the
healing powers attributed to it. This verse is missing from all early
Greek manuscripts and the earliest versions, including the original
Vulgate. Its vocabulary is markedly non-Johannine.

By the time that the Bible was translated into English, however, the verse about the angel had become part of the Textus Receptus. Thus, the KJV and other translations accepted this verse as John 5:4:
KJ21

For an angel went down at a certain season into the pool and troubled
the water. Whosoever then first stepped in, after the troubling of the
water, was made whole of whatsoever disease he had.

Conclusion: If one considers the Textus Receptus as authoritative, then there was indeed an angel. If one goes by older manuscripts, the Bible does not mention an angel, and the tradition upheld by the KJV etc. may be based on folklore.

Would the downvoter be so kind as to explain their objection?
